# Migrating customer stripe payment data from Squarespace to Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am migrating a website that offers subscription services from Square Space to Woo Commerce. Both platforms were configured using our Stripe account.

I am trying to figure out if we can migrate our existing customers into the new Woo Commerce app, so that it will use the same payment information that is already stored in Stripe. Basically we do not want existing customers to have to re-enter their payment information as we know we will lose some customers during this process.

On the Square Space side of things: whenever a new customer is created they create a customer in Stripe, then make a request to the Payment Intent API, associate the intent token to the customer, and then use this to charge the customer every time a payment is due.

On the Woo Commerce side of things: we are using the official Woo Commerce membership and subscription plugins. Whenever a new customer is created, a customer is created in Stripe, a payment method is attached to that user, and then that payment is used to charge the customer.

So my question for anyone who has a deep understanding of WooCommerce, is there a way to update how Woocommerce is integrating with Stripe to try and use the payment intent API tokens that we already have for these existing customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as these Customers were created under your account, you should be able to leverage them.

As a small correction, you would not be referring to existing [Payment **Intents**](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents), but rather existing [Payment **Methods**](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods) attached to the Customer. You could, for example, [retrieve these for any customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list) from the API and then use one of them to [create a new Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method).

Whether WooCommerce needs to do anything to be aware of these existing Customers or Payment Methods I can't say, but you should contact them for support about that.

Comment: Do you happen to know if it is possible to go the other way, meaning create an attached payment method from a payment intent? I understand payment intents is what Stripe is pushing people towards, but we want consistent functionality with our new provider versus the old, which would mean using the attached payments across all our users. If not, I'll have to fork the woocomerce subscription codebase and modify it, and I would rather keep our core code the same as the official release.

Comment: No, if a payment method is used with a one-time payment intent *before* being attached to a Customer, it will be consumed and cannot be used again. You must attach to a customer first, or use `setup_future_usage` to save the card _during_ payment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#web-submit-payment